# Retrieving 12345 from the string "wawawa #99999 hahaha # lalala #12345,no wonder"

Tags: regex

Does anyone know how to retrieve "12345" from the string:

> "wawawa #99999 hahaha # lalala #12345,no wonder"

I tried the pattern `\#(.*?)`, no wonder\, but these returns from #99999 on-wards. I need to start grabbing from the last `'#'` character on-wards.

Thanks.

Comment: This works as well.

(\w+),no wonder

Answer (score 1):

```
#([^#]*),no wonder
```

because `[^#]*` matches only non-`#` characters.

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you need, grabs number after last #, no mater what text is before and what after:

```
#(?!.*#.*)(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do it...

```
#(\d+).*?$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#(?!.*#\d+)(\d+)
```

Gets the number after last # that's followed by a number.

```
(?!.*#\d+)(?<=#)\d+
```

Should also work, with the whole match containing just the number without #, no captures.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add that #12345 may not be the last #

Comment: both match 12345 from all following: `"lklkk #333 #foo #12345 ldsklf"`, `"lklkk #333 #foo #12345 ldsklf #bar ##"`, and `"#234b#12345###sdfgsdf"`. Is that what you want, or should it not match anything if last # is not followed by number?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the last "#" that has some digits after it, then for Java it would look like this:

```
String input = "Retrieving 12345 from the string wawawa #99999 hahaha # lalala #12345,no wonder #ret";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(#\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```